# Method Not Found from Loaded Assembly

Tags: c#, reference, .net-assembly, invoke, method-invocation

I have an application that loads the assembly of another application and invokes methods from that assembly for test purposes. Below is a generic example of this code.

```
testAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom( path );
var classes = testAssembly.GetTypes();
     Type mainForm = classes.Where( c => c.Name == "MainForm" ).SingleOrDefault();
     var form = Activator.CreateInstance( mainForm, null );

     Type secondForm = classes.Where( c => c.Name == "SecondForm" ).SingleOrDefault();
     var sf = Activator.CreateInstance( secondForm , new object[] { form } );

     MethodInfo secondFormMethod = secondForm.GetMethod( "SecondFormMethod" );
     secondFormMethod.Invoke( sf, new object[] { } );
```

This works to a point. The issue is that when the method is fired it eventually leads to a library referenced from the secondFormMethod and comes back with a "Method not found" error.

None of my references seem to be broken in either application.

This method works when fired from the second application I am trying to manipulate.

Not sure what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure this will help, but you can try it... Have you tried removing the trailing spaces on "SecondForm " and "SecondFormMethod "? Especially if you're doing string comparison...

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo from when I pasted it in. :/

Comment: No worries... Also, what is eventList? It's being used to find the method, but it doesn't look like we have any knowledge on how it's doing so...

Comment: Sorry, eventList was a typo also when I was trying to make the code more generic

Answer (score 0):

`LoadFrom()` only loads one assembly, not the assembly and all it's dependencies. You need to call it for each of the assemblies (though just the ones in that particular call stack if you want to avoid loading everything).

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming that you are successfully getting the type for 'secondForm' and 'SecondFormMethod' belongs to 'secondForm', then you can just get the method from that type. Since we don't know what eventList is, this would be a possible quick solution:

```
MethodInfo secondFormMethod = secondForm.GetMethod( "SecondFormMethod" );
```

You may also need to use binding flags depending on where the method is actually defined (i.e. if it's inherited or otherwise).. See binding flags documentation here:
[Binding Flags Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx)